# Glassfish 2.11 is not showing webservices in the admin console

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I am running glassfish 2.1.1 with openesb. I have a problem in that my web services are running correctly, but it is a requirement that the web service be registered in glassfish admin console. Unfortunately the admin console is not showing any of my web services. To clarify, when selecting "Web Services" in navigation the pane on the right shows "No Items Found" but the services are running just fine. I am completely at a loss on how to even troubleshoot this issue. I have turned on finest logging but do not see anything that would help me identify this problem. My project is a simple war application and I am not using any ejb's.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ConsolidatedWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ConsolidatedWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ConsolidatedWS</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Web Service**

```
@SchemaValidation(handler= SchemaValidationHandler.class)
@WebService(serviceName = "ConsolidatedWS", targetNamespace = "http://consolidatedapi/1.0", endpointInterface = "com.ConsolidatedWS")
@HandlerChain(file="/META-INF/SoapHandlerChain.xml")
public class ConsolidatedWSImpl implements ConsolidatedWS {

    @Override
    public CreateConsolidatedOrderResponse createConsolidatedOrder(ConsolidatedOrder order) {
        return new CreateConsolidatedOrderResponse();
    }
}
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
  <endpoint implementation="com.ConsolidatedWSImpl" name="ConsolidatedWS" url-pattern="/ConsolidatedWS"/>
</endpoints>
```

Comment: Remove the listener and the servlet configuration in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that earlier but decided to try it again. I commented out all the sections for the listener and servlet mapping in the web.xml, cleaned built and even examined the war to make sure the change had taken effect. But unfortunately it is still not registering the web service. I am assuming that glassfish will export the webservices when it see's it but where would I find this servlet exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, it was a combination of a couple of things. Thanks to Paul because my web.xml now does not have the listener and servlets.

1. I made the metro webservices-rt provided because this may have been messing with the Glassfish metro implementation.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
       <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
       <version>2.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. As Paul recommended I removed the servlet mappings and listeners

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**sun-javaws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
 </endpoints>
```

**sun-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 8.1 Servlet 2.4//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_4-1.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/consolidated-api</context-root>  
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Glassfish 5. I removed `web.xml` from my project, built the application again, ran the server and it started showing as Webservice application on Glassfish console.

[image: Default glassfish xml]

[image: Glassfish console screenshot]